# How Can I send documents with extensions like xslx or something else in Telegram Bot?

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I am stuck trying to send documents with different extensions to my Telegram using sendDocument().
I use it like

`this.bot.telegram.sendDocument(chatId, 'abc.com/api/telegram/download/${file.path}/${file.name}`

It should download file from S3 first then upload it to telegram. But it works well with pdf, gif, as documentation says. What if I want to send some other docs like xslx, rtf or something else? How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

So, answer was simple enough, I should download file from S3, then pass file.data to `source` field of sendDocument function second parameter:

```
fileService.download(path, name).then(file => ...sendDocument(chatId, {
  source: file.data,
  filename: file.name,
}));
```